# Script to verify the data updated in a table during last 5 minutes

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We hace a web application and we log all the incoming requests of this web app into a Oracle table in real time. This data includes records with different http status codes (200,400...).

We need to create a monitoring/alerting script that runs for every 30 min and checks the data updated in the table in last 5 mins. If records with http status code 200 are less than 100 or records with http status 400 are less than 50 in last 5 mins, then it should raise an alert.

Requesting ideas to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

- Hareesh

Comment: Is there any column that can say when the line has been inserted?

Comment: Yes, there is a column which specifies the time of record insertion in epoch Time

Comment: i've answered your question for both cases. Check that out please

Answer (score 1):

The queries below will return a record only when conditions are met. So you might code the program just to check if there were a row to return.

1. If there is a column to indicate when was the record inserted than you might go on with something like this. Say you have date column named "insert_date".

   ```
    select 'alert'
      from your_table
     where insert_date < sysdate - interval '5' minute
       and status in (100, 200)
     having count(case when status = 200 then 1 else null end) < 100 --  code 200 are less than 100
       or count(case when status = 400 then 1 else null end) < 50 -- status 400 are less than 50
   ```
2. If there is no such column then I can't see any other possibility rather than using flashback query feature:

   ```
    select 'alert'
      from ( select * 
               from your_table
             minus
             select * 
               from your_tables of timestamp systimestamp - interval '5' minute)
     where  status in (100, 200)
    having count(case when status = 200 then 1 else null end) < 100 --  code 200 are less than 100
        or count(case when status = 400 then 1 else null end) < 50 -- status 400 are less than 50
   ```

If you don't already have a scheduling utility, you may want to look into using DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB to create a PL/SQL block that runs every 30 minutes. Inside that block you can call UTL_MAIL.SEND to send an email or text alert.